# Why does my scraper write only some of the data wrong in the csv file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to all this. I managed to crawl through 3600+ items in a page and extract data such as Name, address, phone, mail. All of which I wrote to a .csv file.

My excitement was cut short when I discovered that some of the distributors had missing information (information that's written in the website, and have been written incorrectly to the .csv. Furthermore, some blank columns (like 'B') were created.

Also, I couldn't find a way for the square brackets and the apostrophes to not be written, but I can easily erase them all with LibreOficce Calc.

(In my code I only pasted a few urls out of 3600+, including the ones in the attached picture that show the problem)

```
import scrapy
import requests
import csv



class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
'https://www.bosch-professional.com/ar/es/dl/localizador-de-distribuidores/localizador-de-distribuidores/distribuidor/boschla01586 /zarate/bodelon-edgardo-aristides/?countrySelectorCode=AR', 'https://www.bosch-professional.com/ar/es/dl/localizador-de-distribuidores/localizador-de-distribuidores/distribuidor/boschla01778/zarate/cesario- mariano-rodrigo/?countrySelectorCode=AR', 'https://www.bosch- professional.com/ar/es/dl/localizador-de-distribuidores/localizador-de-distribuidores/distribuidor/boschla00140/zarate/de-vicenzi-elio-mario-g.-rosana-sh/?countrySelectorCode=AR', 'https://www.bosch-professional.com/ar/es/dl/localizador-de-distribuidores/localizador-de-distribuidores/distribuidor/boschla01941/zarate/de-vincenzi-elio-mario-y-rosana-sh/?countrySelectorCode=AR', 'https://www.bosch-professional.com/ar/es/dl/localizador-de-distribuidores/localizador-de-distribuidores/distribuidor/boschla02168/zarate/ferreterias-indufer-s.a./?countrySelectorCode=AR',
]


for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


def parse(self, response):

    marca = []
    names = []
    direcc = []
    locali = []
    telef = []
    mail = []
    site = []


    for item in response.css('div.item-content'):            
        marca.append('Bosch')
        names.append(item.css('p.item-name::text').extract())

        lista_direcc = item.css('p.item-address::text').extract()
        direcc.append(lista_direcc[0].strip())
        locali.append(lista_direcc[1].strip())

        telef.append(item.css('a.btn-phone.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').extract())
        mail.append(item.css('a.btn-email.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').extract())
        site.append(item.css('a.btn-website.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').extract())





    with open('base.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        fieldnames = ['Empresa', 'Nombres', 'Dirección' , 'Localidad', 'Teléfono', 'Mail', 'Sitio Web']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'Empresa' : marca, 'Nombres' : names, 'Dirección' : direcc, 'Localidad' : locali, 'Teléfono' : telef, 'Mail' : mail, 'Sitio Web' : site })

    csvFile.close()
```

[image: Here you can see part of the problem]

You can see an example of what I'm talking about. The program created several extra columns and in some cases shifted the data one column to the left.

I assume that the solution to this is quite simple, as all my previous questions have been. But yet it's puzzling me.

So thanks a lot for any help and for tolerating my poor English. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, rather use the [built-in CSV feed exporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) instead of your own CSV writer method. In other words, `yield` the item instead and let Scrapy handle the CSV.

And secondly, don't write *lists* to the CSV. That is why you get `[[` and `[` in the output. It is likely also the reason for the extra columns due to unnecessary commas (from the lists) in the output.

Another point is you do not need to implement `start_request()`. You can just specify your URLs in a `start_urls` property.

---

Here is an example:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"

    start_urls = [
        # ...
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css('div.item-content'):
            lista_direcc = item.css('p.item-address::text').getall()

            yield {
                'Empresa': 'Bosch',
                'Nombres': item.css('p.item-name::text').get(),
                'Dirección': lista_direcc[0].strip(),
                'Localidad': lista_direcc[1].strip(),
                'Teléfono': item.css('a.btn-phone.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').get(),
                'Mail': item.css('a.btn-email.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').get(),
                'Sitio Web': item.css('a.btn-website.trackingElement.trackingTeaser::text').get(),
            }
```

As mentioned by @Gallaecio in the comments below, it is better to use `get()` instead of `extract()` when you expect a single item (and it is the preferred usage nowadays). Read more here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first

To get the CSV you can run:

`scrapy runspider spidername.py -o output.csv`

Comment: I would add: To avoid lists, when you expect a single element, use `.get()` instead of `.extract()`.

Comment: @Gallaecio I agree that it is clearer to use `get()`. Initially I had that as part of my answer, but I removed it because I realised the usage in the question is actually not a problem. Here `extract()` on `item` (a `Selector`) returns a single item, versus on a `SelectorList` where it returns a list.

Comment: `item.extract()` returns a string, however `item.css('…').extract()` returns a list.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I copied your code and tried it, but encountered some problems: If I delete the start_request function then VS Code notifies me of a problem because the yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse is out of a function. If I erase that part the spider doesn't work. If I leave it and use the yield to write to csv and the command scrapy runspider spidername.py -o output.csv I only get a blank csv file. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @ewha What problems?

Comment: Sorry, was editing my comment, didn't know I cant use enter in comments

Comment: @ewha Can you post the actual VS Code error message? The above code (+import and URLs) runs fine for me.

Comment: I solved that error. Still i get a blank file. In this picture you can see the error displayed in the console for every url: https://imgur.com/QOdb6w4  I can also upload pictures to show you my code, if it's necessary.

Comment: Your `def parse` indentation is wrong. It needs to line up with `start_urls`. Compare it to my example.

Comment: So what's happening is the `parse` function is then not part of the class (rather it is a standalone function), so it considers it missing because it expects it inside the class. (BTW indents are **very** important in Python. If you get it wrong it changes the meaning of things.)

Comment: Oh my god WHY???? Why is it always those tiny details? This is hard, but I'm glad I'm learning it. Thank you very much for your help, you've been really patient. Cheers!!